# How to set min length for models.TextField()?

Tags: django

There seem to be a `max_length` for `CharField` only.  But how about `min_length` for a `TextField()`, is there a way to enforce 100 characters in the `TextField`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You would use a custom [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/), specifically [`MinLengthValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator)

Answer (score 10):

in this case you need to import the `MinLengthValidator` resource from `django.core.validators`, which will look like this:

`from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator`

To use the resource, the model must be written as follows:

```
variable = models.TextField(
        validators=[
            MinLengthValidator(50, 'the field must contain at least 50 characters')
            ]
        )
```

Answer (score 6):

When declaring a Django form

```
cell_phone=forms.CharField(max_length=10,min_length=10);
```

When rendering a form field in Django template

```
{% render_field form1.cell_phone  minlength="10" maxlength="10" %}
```

Underscore is confusing

Answer (score 5):

For `models.Models` field validation:

```
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.db.models.functions import Length

TextField.register_lookup(Length, 'length')

class Foo(models.Mode):
    text_field_name = models.TextField()
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(text_field_name__length__gte=10),
                name="text_field_name_min_length",
            )
        ]
```

Using constrains will create validation on the database level (I think), which will be called on `save()`
This also works for `CharField`.