# Django Rest Framework - serializer fields for only deserialization

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I am writing a simple API for encrypting/decrypting ciphertexts using Django Rest Framework, and I was wondering if it is possible for me to define fiends in a serializer that are only for deserialization (i.e. only for validation). For example, I have a model class called `Message`, and I have a view that allows users to create `Message` objects. When I call `serializer.is_valid()`, I would like to check that a field called `plaintext` is not empty/null, but when I display a `Message` to the user I would like to make the `plaintext` field into a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` instead of directly showing it. In other words, I want users to be able to post a message like this:

```
{ 
  "plaintext": "blah",
  "key": "tunafish"
}
```

and then, after validating it, I would show the user something like:

```
{
  "plaintext": "link/to/plaintext",
  "ciphertext": "link/to/ciphertext",
  "key": "tunafish"
}
```

Is it possible to do this with only one serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Rest Framework serializers have two functions that you can override to have custom (different) behavior for incoming and outgoing fields:  `to_internal_value` (from a dict) and `to_representation` (from your django model instance).

In your case I would make the field a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` and do whatever work you need to in `to_internal_value` to create the relationship between your instance and the `plaintext` instance.

See this documentation on creating a custom field api - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#changes-to-the-custom-field-api

Or read the source here - https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could validate the length of a field without hardcoding? For example, if one of the fields has max_length = 10, how do I validate this from the serializer (or will it be handled by the model)

Comment: @SimonZhu - you can add a field-level `validate_field_name` function to your serializer: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation (or you can just `raise serializers.ValidationError()` inside your `to_internal_value` function).  You can also add a Validator to your Django model as outlined in this SO answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845116/django-how-to-set-min-length-for-models-textfield.  Hope that helps!